# Number formatting in WebSharper Google Visualization

Tags: f#, websharper

I have a question concerning WebSharper's Google Visualization library. I was trying to format the data when the mouse hovers over countries in a Geo Chart.

However, there is the following definition for `Legend` on https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper.google.visualization/blob/master/IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Google.Visualization/Base.fs

```
type Legend [<Inline "{}">] () =
  [<DefaultValue>]
  val mutable position : LegendPosition
  [<DefaultValue>]
  val mutable alignment : LegendAlignment
  [<DefaultValue>]
  val mutable textStyle : TextStyle
```

This does not take into account the `numberFormat` which is used in such charts as GeoChart
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Is there a way to circumvent this (to format tooltips/legends) ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general workaround: the `x?y <- z` dynamic assignment can be used in WebSharper code to get `x.y = z` in the JavaScript translation. So in your case, for example `legend?numberFormat <- ".##"`.

You can also expand the legend type with a helper method for this:

```ml
type Legend with
    [<JavaScript; Inline>]
    member this.WithNumberFormat(format: string) =
        this?numberFormat <- format
        this
```

Or you can create a JavaScript object expression by `New [ "numberformat" => ".##" ]` to use as the Legend object.

WebSharper's Google.Visualization typed bindings are a bit outdated. We will get around to review it completely someday, but feel free to create a pull request if you encounter any missing API functionality.